# Main container background breaks in FF and chrome. Why?

Tags: xhtml

I am working on a site (new to HTML/CSS). I have a main container div which holds other layout (div, table etc) elements. I added a background img (attach: background-container.png) to the main container div to give a drop shadow effect (similar to this attached screenshot of a site: drop_shadow_example_site.png). Surprisingly, the technique works for IE6,7,8 but not for firefox and chrome. I am attaching two screenshots: 1.screenshot in firefox and chrome (attach:comp does not work in FF & chrom.png) and 2. screenshot in IE6,7,8 etc (comp works in IE6,7,8.png).

I have also attached a zipped code files (html,css,img etc).

[image: container Drop Shadow]
[image: Sample Site Screenshot]
[image: FF and Chrome Screenshot]
[image: IE6,7,8 screenshot]

Link to SiteCode.zip
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27899629/SiteCode.zip

Thanks for your help.
Regards,
appu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the lines below to your css:

```
.container {
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: ok that masterstroke solves it. Code you pls explain the logic. thnks.

Comment: Read here about clearing in css [link](http://css-tricks.com/795-all-about-floats/) - "The Great Collapse" section